# Force textbox Value to put in float data

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is a part of my code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string NumSaisie = textNumSaisie.Text;
                DateTime Jour = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);
                string NumCpt = txtNdC.Text;
                string Lib = txtLib.Text;
                string Descri = txtDescri.Text;
                float Debit = txtDebit.Text;
                float Credit = txtCredit.Text;

                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO Saisie2 VALUES ('" + NumSaisie + "', '"+ Jour + "', '"+ NumCpt + "', '"+ Lib + "', '"+ Descri + "', '"+ Debit + "', '"+ Credit + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("ok");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

I'm trying to put data in an Access document for my personnel accounting; however, I have some difficulties about incompatibilities of data. My idea with the variables id to force textbox values to be in a good format so they will be accepted by Access.

I see in my error that we cannot put a text value in float value, so I a, searching in each value after the dot to see which one will be good to use (to replace `.Text`), however I haven't any idea of which one.

Comment: `float.Parse` perhaps?

Comment: And please use parameterized queries instead of SQL string concatenation. Might not matter for your personal project, but it is open to [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: listen to Klaus, listen carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the text is only the number and nothing else, you could use `float.Parse(txtDebit.Text)` to convert from string to float.

Comment: You may want to use `float.TryParse` to verify the the data is actually a float